# allow 0 in mm/dd/yyyy format for month at start using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have one textbox and keypad design to take date of birth by user.

HTML code

```js
        Memory  = "0";      // initialise memory variable
        Current = "0";      //   and value of Display ("current" value)
        Operation = 0;      // Records code for eg * / etc.
        MAXLENGTH = 8;     // maximum number of digits before decimal!
    
    function format(input, format, sep) {
        var output = "";
        var idx = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < format.length && idx < input.length; i++) {
            output += input.substr(idx, format[i]);
            if (idx + format[i] < input.length) output += sep;
            idx += format[i];
        }

        output += input.substr(idx);

        return output;
    }
    
    function AddDigit(dig)          //ADD A DIGIT TO DISPLAY (keep as 'Current')
     { if (Current.indexOf("!") == -1)  //if not already an error
        { if (    (eval(Current) == 0)
                  && (Current.indexOf(".") == -1)
             ) { Current = dig;
               } else
               { Current = Current + dig;
               };
          Current = Current.toLowerCase(); //FORCE LOWER CASE
        } else
        { Current = "Hint! Press 'Clear'";  //Help out, if error present.
        };
      
     
     if (Current.length > 0) {
      Current = Current.replace(/\D/g, "");
            Current = format(Current, [2, 2, 4], "/");
        }
      
    
       document.calc.display.value = Current.substring(0, 10);
     }
    
    
    function Clear()                //CLEAR ENTRY
     { Current = "0";
       document.calc.display.value = Current;
     }
```

```html
<form Name="calc" method="post">
          <input class="intxt1" autocomplete="off" id="ptdob" maxlength="6" name="display" type="tel" value="" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"><button class="cancel-icon" type="reset" OnClick="Clear()"></button>     
          <div class="calculator" style="margin: 30px auto;">
     <!-- Screen and clear key -->
         <div class="keys">
        <!-- operators and other keys -->
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('1')">1</span>
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('2')">2</span>
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('3')">3</span>

        <span OnClick="AddDigit('4')">4</span>
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('5')">5</span>
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('6')">6</span>

        <span OnClick="AddDigit('7')">7</span>
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('8')">8</span>
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('9')">9</span>

        <span OnClick="AddDigit('0')" style="width: 166px;">0</span>
        <span class="clear" OnClick="Clear()">
                <div class="xBox">X</div>
              </span>
        </div>
         </div>
    </form>
```

I am taking date in MM/DD/YYYY format. Above code is working fine. It takes digits by automatically adding `/` in between digits. But when user wants to enter date like 05/11/2016, for month it does not allowing to take 0 at start. when user clicks 0 from keypad and then 5 for example, it coverts 0 to 5. It does not take 0 at the beginning. And it adds next clicked digit to month. e.g. 51/11/2016 like this.

How should I allow 0 at the beginning for month?

**NOTE:**  I have my web page design for above is like below image:

[image]

User should not type directly in textbox. Textbox should have inputs from the keypad that I have design. So no use of applying date functionality on textbox like `type="date"` or using datepicker or any plugins as user is not directly using textbox.

Comment: You'd save yourself a lot of headache and testing by using http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Why did you add this, `type="tel"`, try `type="date"`

Comment: Why are you using eval()?

Comment: @Matthew Harwood, Lahiru Ashan : User should not type digits directly in textbox. Textbox is taking input from the keypad that I have design on page when user clicks digits from it, in this case. So I can not apply any plugins on textbox that I don't want here.

Comment: @Matthew Harwood please guide me how my `AddDigit` function should be for taking digits from keypad, if that is creating my above problem of taking 0 at start. I am not fully aware of javascript.

Comment: Why not use datepicker?

Comment: @Trafalgar D Law I have commented it previously. I can not use any date functionality directly on textbox as user is not typing/ taking date from textbox. User should click on keypad digits to take date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite close, but there are definitely better ways of doing this, as suggested in the comments (DatePicker, moment.js(), etc.).

However, looking at your code, you have a few problems.

`Current = "0";` - why are we setting the default value to '0'? It should be `Current = "";`.

`if(eval(Current) == 0)` - I have no idea what this is doing. However, if the first digit is '0', then you're doing `if(eval(0) == 0)`. i.e. `if(false == false)`. i.e. `if(true)`.

`eval` is evil, but if you insist on doing it that way, then you can switch that line to `if(eval(Current) === undefined)`.

Lastly, in `Clear`, `Current = "0";` - same as before. `Current = "";`.

What you have isn't a bad first attempt at JS, so keep practicing. Some tips:

- Lose the Title Case var/function names.
- Use `var` whenever defining variables (unless using ES6 - then use `let`/`const`)
- Don't recreate the wheel - use libraries that already exist.
- Use correct HTML attributes - `onClick` over `OnClick`.

```js
        Memory  = "0";      // initialise memory variable
        Current = "";      //   and value of Display ("current" value)
        Operation = 0;      // Records code for eg * / etc.
        MAXLENGTH = 8;     // maximum number of digits before decimal!
    
    function format(input, format, sep) {
        var output = "";
        var idx = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < format.length && idx < input.length; i++) {
            output += input.substr(idx, format[i]);
            if (idx + format[i] < input.length) output += sep;
            idx += format[i];
        }

        output += input.substr(idx);

        return output;
    }
    
    function AddDigit(dig)          //ADD A DIGIT TO DISPLAY (keep as 'Current')
     { if (Current.indexOf("!") == -1)  //if not already an error
        { if (    (eval(Current) === undefined)
                  && (Current.indexOf(".") == -1)
             ) { Current = dig;
               } else
               { Current = Current + dig;
               };
          Current = Current.toLowerCase(); //FORCE LOWER CASE
        } else
        { Current = "Hint! Press 'Clear'";  //Help out, if error present.
        };
      
     
     if (Current.length > 0) {
      Current = Current.replace(/\D/g, "");
            Current = format(Current, [2, 2, 4], "/");
        }
      
    
       document.calc.display.value = Current.substring(0, 10);
     }
    
    
    function Clear()                //CLEAR ENTRY
     { Current = "";
       document.calc.display.value = Current;
     }
```

```html
<form Name="calc" method="post">
          <input class="intxt1" autocomplete="off" id="ptdob" maxlength="6" name="display" type="tel" value="" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"><button class="cancel-icon" type="reset" OnClick="Clear()"></button>     
          <div class="calculator" style="margin: 30px auto;">
     <!-- Screen and clear key -->
         <div class="keys">
        <!-- operators and other keys -->
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('1')">1</span>
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('2')">2</span>
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('3')">3</span>

        <span OnClick="AddDigit('4')">4</span>
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('5')">5</span>
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('6')">6</span>

        <span OnClick="AddDigit('7')">7</span>
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('8')">8</span>
        <span OnClick="AddDigit('9')">9</span>

        <span OnClick="AddDigit('0')" style="width: 166px;">0</span>
        <span class="clear" OnClick="Clear()">
                <div class="xBox">X</div>
              </span>
        </div>
         </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for information and answer. Really this will help me to progress in JS. I was aware of some plugins and textbox functionality also but I could not use that in this case as the requirement is different.